# could someone help me solve this recurrence using substitution method?

Tags: algorithm, math, recurrence

could someone help me solve this recurrence? 
T(n) = 8T(n/2) + n^2 is T(n) =  O(n^3) using the substitution method. Considering T(1)=1

Answer (score 0):

One way to approach this recurrence relation, is [`rsolve`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/solvers/solvers.html#sympy.solvers.recurr.rsolve) from [sympy](https://www.sympy.org), Python's symbolic math library:

```
from sympy import Function, rsolve, log
from sympy.abc import k, n

f = Function('f')
g = Function('g')

# T(n) = 8T(n/2) + n^2   T(1) = 1
T = f(n) - 8 * f(n / 2) - n ** 2 - 3
Tk = T.subs({n: 2 ** k, f(n): g(k), f(n / 2): g(k - 1)})

s = rsolve(Tk, g(k), {g(0): 1})
print("solution for k:", s.cancel())
print("solution for n:", s.subs({k: log(n, 2)}).simplify().cancel())

for k in range(0, 11):
    print(f"k={k}, n={2 ** k}, T(n)={(17 * n ** 3 - 3) // 7 - n ** 2}")
```

This outputs the solution `(17*n^3 - 3)/7 - n^2`.
Note that the function is only defined for `n` a power of 2.
The first values for `n=1,2,4,8,...` are `1, 15, 139, 1179, 9691, 78555, 632539, 5076699, 40679131, 325695195, 2606610139`

Comment: Was this answer helpful?

Answer (score 0):

Just try to expand the relation and keep continue by the induction:

```
T(n) = 8 T(n/2) + n^2 =
       8(8T(n/4) + (n/2)^2) + n^2 = 8^2 T(n/2^2) + 8 (n/2)^2 + n^2
```

As each time `n` is divided by `2` each time, if `n = 2^k`, the length of the series `k = log(n)`:

```
T(n) = n^2 + 8 (n/2)^2 + 8^2 (n/2^2)^2 + ... + 8^log(n) T(1)
     = sum_{i=0}^{log(n)} 8^i (n/2^i)^2
```

Rewrite the relation by `2^2i = 4^i`:

```
T(n) = sum_{i=0}^{log(n)} 8^i/4^i n^2 = n^2 * sum_{i=0}^{log(n)} 2^i
     = n^2 (2^(log(n)+1) - 1) = \Theta(n^3)
```

Notice that `2^log(n) = n`.